# cleveref: second hyperlink set incorrectly in ranges

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref

Consider the following MWE with `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
Page one
\label{one}
\newpage
Page two
\label{two}
\newpage
\cpagerefrange{one}{two}
\end{document}
```

The resulting document looks correct, but the hyperlink of the second part of the range ('2') is wrong, it points to the same page as the first.

Is this simply a bug, or am I missing something essential here?

Comment: Untested, but those labels have nothing to anchor to. Try, in this case, adding `\phantomsection` before each label.

Comment: Normally the anchors come from sections, equation or theorem counters, but in this mwe there are none.

Comment: The labels are page labels, why do they need sections, and why only for the second part of the range? I am finishing a book with quite a lot of cross-refs to page and figure ranges. Does this mean I have to manually insert a `\phantomsection` every time I set a label?

Comment: Labels can be used whenever there is some `\refstepcounter` or another command that sets an anchor which could be labelled. So in your case they aren't page labels but rather "labels in the wild".

Comment: @Circumscribe; My question isn't about what is displayed but about where the hyperlinks in the PDF point to.

Comment: @TeXnician I am still not completely sure I understand the concept or rather how to smartly deal with this. So I have a book with parts, chapters, sections etc. and in this I regularly crossref to page and figure ranges. Do I always have to insert a `\phantomsection` to get correct hyperlinks? This does not look like an unusual setup to me. Isn't there some general solution to this or do I have to check every label individually whether it needs a `\phantomsection` command?

Comment: Well, page ranges without some anchor are kind of unusual. Don't you have some object on that page which you want to reference (like a section, a figure etc.)? A `\pageref` on such a label would be quite usual (e.g. from one section to the next one). All labels that are not bound to any "regular object" need a construction like `\phantomsection` (or a `\refstepcounter` or anything else that sets a target anchor). You could use the low-level hyperref commands if you really want to mess around with arbitrary labels…

Comment: @TeXnician I have sections and stuff, but if the two pages which define the range are inside the same section I seem to need a `\phantomsection`
. At least in humanities, this is not so unusual. The whole reason I refer to a page range is because I want to refer to a "text unit" which is smaller than a section.

Comment: Hyperrefs needs anchors. Pagesrefs them self does not.

Comment: @TeXnician: lower level 'labeling' (rather hypertargeting) will give destination labels, but nothing that is usable by `cref`, in my point of view. But you and daleif are right: Without proper `\phantomsection` or `\refstepcounter` there is nothing to label or to refer to at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Links need an anchor. `hyperref` sets such an anchor when `\refstepcounter` is issued. So references and links to normal numbered objects normally work without problems. But if you set a label "in the wild" you need to tell `hyperref` which anchors it should use by issuing a `\phantomsection`.

You can link to pages as a whole with `\hyperpage` (this is e.g. used by the index), but then you need an (expandable) method to get the page number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
Page one
\phantomsection\label{one}
\newpage
Page two
\phantomsection\label{two}
\newpage
\cpageref{one}, \pageref{one}, \cpageref{two}, \pageref{two}
\cpagerefrange{one}{two}

\hyperpage{\getpagerefnumber{two}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything speaking against something along the lines of `\pretocmd{\label}{\phantomsection}{}{}`?

Comment: Well it will break all normal \label uses - the anchors will no longer be e.g. at the begin of a section but at the position where you issue the \label.